# Deserialize ActiveRecord from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, deserialization, mass-assignment

I would like to save query result into redis using JSON serialization and query it back.

Getting query results to json is pretty easy:

```
JSON.generate(Model.all.collect {|item| item.attributes})
```

However I did not find a proper way to deserialize it back to ActiveRecord. The most straight-forward way:

```
JSON.parse(@json_string).collect {|item| Model.new.from_json(item)}
```

Gives me an error:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id
```

So id gets empty. I thought of just using OpenStruct for the views instead of ActiveRecord but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could instantiate the new object from JSON and then assign the id afterwards. Probably best to create your own method for this:

```
class Model
  def self.from_json_with_id(params = {})
    params = JSON.parse(params)
    model = new(params.reject {|k,v| k == "id"})
    model.id = params["id"]
    model
  end
end
```

Or maybe just override the `from_json()` method.

Comment: Though I am suprised there is no built in support for this. This sounds good. Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, I was winging this. You might want to use `allocate` instead of `new` if you want ActiveRecord to realize it's not a new object in the database

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this:

```
JSON.parse(@json_string).each do |item|
     item.delete(:id) # I tested it in my case it also works without this line
     object=Model.create(item)
end
```

If the host that created the JSON adds a JSON root you might have to use `item[1]` instead of `item`.

Comment: The json items came from the database in the first place. Using model.create will attempt to create the item in the database and will fail since the item already exists.