# Create an ActiveRecord Instance from Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

What is the best way to create a new Ruby/Rails object without triggering any database actions?

For example if I have a Task class

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_one :location

end
```

And I want to create one from cached data that looks something like this

```
task_json = { 
  id: 1, 
  title: 'My Task', 
  tags: [ 
    { title: 'Tag1' }, 
    { title: 'Tag2'} 
  ]
  location: { lat: 46.0, lon: -120.1 } 
}
```

And I want to reconstitute the object, but not trigger any database interactions.

```
@task = Task.new
@task.id = task_json['id']
@task.title = task_json['title']
@task.location = Location.new(:lat => task_json['location']['lat'], :lon => task_json['location']['lon'])

@task.tags = ...
```

Ideally, there would be no chance of saves or database interaction in any way once the object is built.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use `JSON.parse` on your JSON string `task_json` this way:

```
task = Task.new(JSON.parse(task_json))
```

Comment: The json response is not an exact representation of the object so this doesn't work perfectly, but I can do some of this.

Comment: Well, if it's not an exact representation, I'm afraid you will have to build your object manually. Unless there is another way I am not aware of ?

Comment: With this I get a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at, id...`

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can pass a second parameter to .new


`task = Task.new(JSON.parse(task_json), without_protection: true)`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879637/deserialize-activerecord-from-json for a custom `from_json` method which can be used to solve the `protected_attributes` problem

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to create a new Ruby/Rails object without triggering any database actions?
>
> For example if I have a Task class
>
> `class Task < ActiveRecord::Base`

### Plain Old Ruby Objects

If you want a PORO (plain old Ruby object) that does not persist, why even subclass `ActiveRecord::Base`? You could just put this in any autoloadable path like `app/models/task.rb`:

```
class Task
  attr_reader :tags, :location, ...
  def initialize(...)
    @tags = ...
    @location = ...
    ...
  end
end
```

Then create it elsewhere like:

```
task = Task.new(...)
```

And you can then access its parts like:

```
task.tags
```

Where you either pass in the parsed JSON, the JSON string, args, etc.

However, the hash itself from `JSON.parse(some_json_string)` is a Ruby object, so you could just as easily use it. It won't trigger any DB operations either. :) The main reason you might use a class like Task is to make it a little more obvious what it is and what to expect from it, but a hash is easy enough to work with also. Just depends.

If you really want a read-only ActiveRecord model, you could use one of the several gems out there for it. I wrote one that a few others have contributed to called [activerecord-be_readonly](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-be_readonly), but the times you'd need something like that should be few and far between, and it is more geared towards reading data from the DB and then attempting to not allow DB updates to that specific table via that model.

### Only Making ActiveRecord Model Instance Read-only When Created From JSON

In your comment, you said you only want to make it read-only if pulled from cache, if I understand correctly.

Take a look at how the [activerecord-be_readonly](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-be_readonly) gem is altering AR behavior here: https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-be_readonly/blob/master/lib/activerecord-be_readonly/model.rb

I'm guessing you'll want to set a flag when you initialize the model with a JSON hash that similar methods could look at and raise `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` or similar when that flag is set.

This only protects the model that you use these methods in though. If you have associations to other models, it will not protect them unless they use a similar method. In the end, you may be better off with POROs and regular AR models, if you absolutely must do this.

However, this sounds like it is going to be a pain to use. I'd avoid anything that makes the user (or developer) scratch his/her head too much.

Comment: I only want it to act this way when I'm loading json from the cache.  Otherwise, I want all the ActiveRecord functionality.  We have plenty of times where we are reading/writing from MySql, but to improve performance in search, the list item response is cached in json (for an api as well as web).  I'd like to use the AR class so "render @task" in a view works with either object AR or PORO.  I suppose I could duplicate all the classes and disguise them for rendering, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: One other quick thing, you said "but to improve performance in search, the list item response is cached in json". AR already caches, and if you are having performance issues, are you doing n+1 queries or have you optimized with `include:`, indices, additional DB optimization, caching responses at the webserver level, diff server/server optimization, reduce calls from client, etc.?

Comment: We get a lot of traffic. The item in the list has a lot of child/nested objects.  Even with including child objects, caching the result his helpful.  We currently cache the html in memcache, but I'm interested in caching  json so it can be used by the api (iphone, android, windows) as well as the web app.

Comment: I think I found a way to avoid triggering DB actions - by calling task[:location] = Location.new and task[:tags] << Tag.new I don't see db transactions in the logs.  Also adding readonly! to the resulting task would stop any accidental saves.  What do you think of this approach?

Comment: If it were me, I'd separate the services/actions that provide read-write and read-only data. Working with both at once might be confusing to other developers and might be more likely to create support issues. BTW- I'm big fan of your company/site. Use it periodically. Great info.

Comment: Writing to the hash value approach didn't actually work so I tried something else.  I found I was able to use getters and setters with memoization to set associations manually and stop hitting the db.  It is complicated, but I really like how our list pages no longer hit the db in the common case.  Responses are very fast < 50ms.  Thanks for your thoughts.  I'll post more if I find a cleaner solution.

Comment: See: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/36253916b0b788d6ded56669d37c96ed05c92c5c Despite the memoist gem, I'm not sure I'd use it a lot. Glad you found something you like though. Don't knock anything in Ruby/Rails that makes you happy. It's usually a good thing, and you want as many of those days as you can get. :)

Comment: Right, I'm using the memoize pattern - e.g. "@_task ||= ".  That way I can set it directly and avoid the other parts of the method that would trigger database events.

Comment: I think you can use `from_json` like this

json = { name: 'bob', age: 22, awesome:true }.to_json
person = Person.new
person.from_json(json) # => #<Person:0x007fec5e7a0088 @age=22, @awesome=true, @name="bob">
person.name            # => "bob"
person.age             # => 22
person.awesome         # => true